# Swift 2 - POST requests don't get parameters added

Tags: json, post, swift2, alamofire

Following up to a question someone asked on the Alamofire github issues that never got answered because I want the answer as well.

> Doing a simple request with GET adds my parameters nicely, but doing a
>   POST doesn't.
>
> ```
> let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
>
> Alamofire.request(.POST, "url", parameters: parameters)
> .responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
>   print("request: \(request)")
> }
> ```
>
> returns
>
> ```
> request: Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9864109cb0> { URL: https://api.github.com/repos/BasThomas/junk/issues })
>  while
>
> let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
>
> Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: parameters)
> .responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
>   print("request: \(request)")
> }
> ```
>
> returns
>
> ```
> request: Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9ef07ef0f0> { URL: https://api.github.com/repos/BasThomas/junk/issues?foo=bar })
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of a POST are added to the request body, not to the URL. This is due to the common conventions between GET and POST.

### Custom Parameter Encoding

If you need to append them to the URL (sounds like you do), then I'd suggest you take a look at the `.Custom` [ParameterEncoding](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0#parameter-encoding) type. That will allow you to follow the same logic as the encode method, but append the parameters however you like.

Also, the methods inside the `ParameterEncoding` enum have now all been made public so you'll have access to the query parameter splitting and escaping.